# Why does gradle-7.4-bin.zip prevent me from using javax.servlet?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Afer updating Android Studio to `Electric Eel` I updated my `gradle-wrapper.properties` to use gradle 7.5:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip`

And also my gradle files to:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'`

When I did that, all my imports of `javax.servlet` stopped working.

If I revert back to `gradle-7.4-bin.zip` then the imports work just fine.

What is different about `gradle-7.5-bin.zip` and do I need to worry about it for future releases?

The `javax.servlet` dependency I believe comes from:

```
api 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.12.v20130726'
api 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.12.v20130726'
```

Do I need to change how I add that?

Edit: It was mentioned on a comment that mixing `7.5` and `7.4` was probably not right but that is what Android Studio suggests:

[image]

Edit: Even adding `implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016'` doesn't add the `javax.servlet` packages.

Comment: "And also my gradle files to" -- that's weird. I would have expected `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.0`, since I thought the idea was that the AGP plugin version was updated to match the Gradle version. But I don't see 7.5.0 in Google's Maven repository.  `javax.servlet.*` is not directly in `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet`, based on the download from mvnrepository.com. I didn't check in the other one, and it might come from some sort of dependency. But, 8.1.12 is nearly a decade old. Are you sure it is wise to use ancient server code, on an OS not designed to be a server?

Comment: I checked on a different project I have and it is also suggesting upgrading to `7.4.0` on the `AGP` and `Gradle` to `7.5`. As far as the old `jetty` server, last I tried to update it, Android was lacking something `jetty` needed, however I have since stopped supporting really old Android versions so I'll have to check if that is still a problem.

Comment: I created a new project using the templates on Android studio and it did the same `7.4.0` AGP and `7.5` gradle mix.

Comment: Even adding `implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016'` doesn't add the `javax.servlet` packages.

Comment: Adding `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1` fixes the issue. Very bizarre. On the plus side this got me down the path of updating Jetty and it looks like I can go all the way to `9.2` while targeting Android 5+.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution though I still don't understand the issue.

Jetty `8.1.12` comes with:

`org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:3.0.0.v201112011016`

If I use `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1` instead then it works fine.